# how to access the front camera of a device when camera app opens in unity

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine

- More generally, If a device has two camera,how to acess the frontcamera when camera is selected from app, is there any way to initialize one of them in particular?
- this is my code that i have written for camera.

this is my script for camera plane controle

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class CameraPlaneController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera _targetCam;

    ScreenOrientation orientation;
    float height = 0;
    float width = 0;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {

    float Screenheight = (float)_targetCam.orthographicSize* 2.0f; 
    float Screenwidth = Screenheight * Screen.width / Screen.height;
    height = Screenheight ;
    width = Screenwidth;
    this.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,0,91.6f);

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(90,180,0);
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(width/10, 1.0f, height/10);
    #elif UNITY_WEBPLAYER
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(90,180,0);
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(width/10, 1.0f, height/10);
    #endif

    orientation = Screen.orientation;

    Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
    if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait||
        Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown) {

        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(90,180,0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(width/10, 1.0f, height/10);

        #elif UNITY_ANDROID
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,270,90);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(height/10, 1.0f, width/10);
        #elif UNITY_IOS
        if( Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown)
        {
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,270,90);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,90,270);
        }
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1*height/10, 1.0f, width/10);
        #endif
    } else if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Landscape) {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(90,180,0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(width/10, 1.0f, height/10);

        #elif UNITY_ANDROID
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(90,180,0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(width/10, 1.0f, height/10);
        #elif UNITY_IOS
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-90,0,0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1*width/10, 1.0f, height/10);

        #endif
    }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    if (orientation != Screen.orientation) {

        int screenHeight_1 = Screen.height;
        int screenWidth_1 = Screen.width;
        if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait||
            Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown) {

            if(screenHeight_1 < screenWidth_1)
            {
                int tempvalue = screenWidth_1;
                screenWidth_1 = screenHeight_1;
                screenHeight_1 = tempvalue;
            }
            float Screenheight = (float)_targetCam.orthographicSize* 2.0f; 
            float Screenwidth = Screenheight * screenWidth_1 / screenHeight_1;
            height = Screenheight ;
            width = Screenwidth;
            #if UNITY_ANDROID
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,270,90);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(height/10, 1.0f, width/10);
            #elif UNITY_IOS
            if( Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown)
            {
                transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,270,90);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,90,270);
            }

            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1*height/10, 1.0f, width/10);
            #endif
        } else if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Landscape||
                   Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft) {

            if(screenHeight_1 > screenWidth_1)
            {
                int tempvalue = screenWidth_1;
                screenWidth_1 = screenHeight_1;
                screenHeight_1 = tempvalue;
            }

            float Screenheight = (float)_targetCam.orthographicSize* 2.0f; 
            float Screenwidth = Screenheight * screenWidth_1 / screenHeight_1;
            height = Screenheight ;
            width = Screenwidth;

            #if UNITY_ANDROID
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(90,180,0);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(width/10, 1.0f, height/10);
            #elif UNITY_IOS
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-90,0,0);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1*width/10, 1.0f, height/10);
            #endif
        }
        else if(Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight)
        {
            if(screenHeight_1 > screenWidth_1)
            {
                int tempvalue = screenWidth_1;
                screenWidth_1 = screenHeight_1;
                screenHeight_1 = tempvalue;
            }

            float Screenheight = (float)_targetCam.orthographicSize* 2.0f; 
            float Screenwidth = Screenheight * screenWidth_1 / screenHeight_1;
            height = Screenheight ;
            width = Screenwidth;
            #if UNITY_ANDROID
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-90,0,0);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(width/10, 1.0f, height/10);
            #elif UNITY_IOS

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(90,180,0);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1*width/10, 1.0f, height/10);
            #endif
        }
        orientation = Screen.orientation;
    }
    }


    }
```

this is my script for device camera controle

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System.Collections;
    public class DeviceCameraController : MonoBehaviour {

public enum CameraMode
{
    FACE_C,
    DEFAULT_C,
    NONE
}
[HideInInspector]
public WebCamTexture cameraTexture; 

private bool isPlay = false;
//public CameraMode e_CameraMode;
GameObject e_CameraPlaneObj;
int matIndex = 0;

ScreenOrientation orientation;
public bool isPlaying
{
    get{
        return isPlay;
    }
}
// Use this for initialization  
void Awake()  
{  
    StartCoroutine(CamCon());  
    e_CameraPlaneObj = transform.FindChild ("CameraPlane").gameObject;

}

// Update is called once per frame  
void Update()  
{  
    if (isPlay) {  
        if(e_CameraPlaneObj.activeSelf)
        {
            e_CameraPlaneObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = cameraTexture;
        }

    }
}

IEnumerator CamCon()  
{  
    yield return Application.RequestUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam);  
    if (Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam))  
    {  
        #if UNITY_EDITOR_WIN 
        cameraTexture = new WebCamTexture();  
        #elif UNITY_EDITOR_OSX
        cameraTexture = new WebCamTexture(960,640);  
        #elif UNITY_IOS
        cameraTexture = new WebCamTexture(960,640);
        #elif UNITY_ANDROID
        cameraTexture = new WebCamTexture(960,640);  

        #else
        cameraTexture = new WebCamTexture(); 
        #endif
        cameraTexture.Play();
        isPlay = true;  
    }  
}

public void StopWork()
{
    this.cameraTexture.Stop();
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a new WebCamTexture without providing a device name automatically uses the first camera Unity finds. Instead, you need to find the device name of the front facing camera and use that.

WebCamTexture has a static variable called `devices` that lets you iterate through all the known cameras connected to the computer. Each device has a boolean `isFrontFacing` which tells you which way the camera is facing. In your camera initialization you can do this:

```
string selectedDeviceName = "";
WebCamDevices[] allDevices = WebCamTexture.devices;
for(int i = 0; i < allDevices.Length; i++)
{
    if (allDevices[i].isFrontFacing)
    {
        selectedDeviceName = allDevices[i].name;
        break;
    }
}

this.cameraTexture = new WebCamTexture(selectedDeviceName, 960, 640);
```

This will work in the majority of cases. I have noticed some cameras do not list a device name, which means you can't construct a new `WebCamTexture` with that device. Other cameras do not correctly report if they are front-facing. As far as I know there isn't a good way to handle these cases.

Comment: when i used this script i got the value of selectedDeviceName as camera 1.. i believe camera 1 is my front camera .. how can i activate camera 1 as default camera in my script

Comment: cameraTexture =new WebCamTexture("//enter the name of your camera", 960, 640);

Comment: name of the camera can be taken from selectedDeviceName